# Complex merging of two lists: one template and many permutations

Tags: python

This is a rather particular request. Rather than explain the concept abstractly, I will give an example of what I'd like to do.

I have one 'template' list or string: [
X,G,X]... or 'XGX'

And many 'permutation' lists: 
[U,U] , [U,C] , [C,U] , [C,C]... or 'UU', 'UC', 'CU', 'CC'

And I'd like to get the following list: 
[UGU, CGU, UGC, CGC]

Anyone have any ideas of how to attack this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming perm_list = `[['u', 'u'], ['u', 'c'], ['c', 'u'], ['c', 'c']]` then you could do `['G'.join(x) for x in perm_list]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def resolveTemplates(_template, perms):
    for perm in perms:
        template = list(_template)
        perm = iter(perm)
        for i,char in enumerate(template):
            if char != "X": continue
            template[i] = next(perm)
        yield template
```

Output:

```
In [113]: print(*resolveTemplates('XGX', ['UU', 'UC', 'CU', 'CC']), sep='\n')
['U', 'G', 'U']
['U', 'G', 'C']
['C', 'G', 'U']
['C', 'G', 'C']
```